# How would you re-order the reordered list back to its previous form?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
element =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
index_list =  [3,5,6,1,2,4,0]

result = [element[i] for i in index_list]
print(result)
```

this would eventually give me a ordered list based on the index list which would give
['d', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'a'].

How would you re-order this already re-ordered list back to its previous form which would be ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']? I tried using the given index list again but it did not returned it back, but simply gave me a new list. Would there be any way I could still use the given index list to reorder the list back?

Comment: What do you mean re-order? That original list and order is already stored in the variable `element` The new ordered list is called `result`

Comment: Nothing has changed at all. You didn't change your `element` list. It's still intact in its original order. Just add `print(element)` at the bottom and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the opposite:

```
reordered = [None] * len(result)
for index, e in zip(index_list, result):
    reordered[index] = e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process `index_list` to do the reverse permutation:

```
index_list =  [3,5,6,1,2,4,0]    
reverse = [i for i, n in sorted(enumerate(index_list), key=lambda x: x[1])]

original = [result[i] for i in reverse]
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
print([a for a, b in sorted(zip(result, index_list), key=lambda x: x[1])])
```